# MariadDB - error establishing a database connection wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

I know I know, this question has been certainly asked millions of times and many tutorials are available. However I still cannot resolve it, I guess my issue is with mariadb. When I try to `sudo systemctl start mariadb`nothing happened and my connection is killed. How should I resolve my mariadb connection issue? Seems I cannot even check if it works.

Please advise

Comment: What does it say when you run `sudo systemctl status mariadb`?

Comment: @ozgur mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) (Result: timeout)
 Main PID: 868 (mysqld_safe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service

Comment: @ozgur Dec 05 21:10:00 izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Dec 05 21:10:00 izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz mariadb-prepare-db-dir[741]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, not...done.
Dec 05 21:10:00 izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz mysqld_safe[868]: 201205 21:10:00 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz.err'.
Dec 05 21:10:01 izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz mysqld_safe[868]: 201205 21:10:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

Comment: is there any error here ? `var/lib/mysql/izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz.err`

Comment: @ozgur -bash: var/lib/mysql/izj6ch2w4d6eaitgcw8zbgz.err: No such file or directory

Comment: Please look into `var/lib/mysql` and search for `.err` files. They may reveal if there are any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225558/discussion-between-chinaxiaohong-and-ozgur).